# Making images work in popup created through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a popup window that all of the data is added through javascript. However all of the images that get added don't get resolved. How can I make the images work without providing an absolute url?

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2zKa/)**

```
$("#openPopup").click(function() {
    var win = window.open();
    var body = $(win.document.body);

    $(body).append($("<img src='/img/logo.png' style='background:blue' />"));
    $(body).append($("<div>Hello World</div>"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

window.location.hostname should do it.

```
$(body).append($("<img src='http://"+window.location.hostname+"/img/logo.png' style='background:blue' />"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/babumxx/v2zKa/2/

http://fiddle.jshell.net/babumxx/v2zKa/2/show/

Comment: I am cloning a complex table, with many images, and appending it to the popup window, to provide a simple way of printing the table. Is there no way to set the window to use the same location without iterating through all the imgs and alternating the src attribute?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

UI elements are best used as CSS backgrounds:

```
#openPopup {
     background-image:url(img/logo.png);
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-position:10px 10px;
}
```

CSS paths are relative to the location of the **stylesheet**, not the page itself.